# Saving NSNumber core data

Tags: ios

how can i save a number within core data from a UITextField , i know its something stupid but its annoying and i cant get round it !

im doing this right now and i keep getting nulls

```
NSLog(@"SaveData(CLIENT)");
[self dismissKeyboard];
Client *client = (Client *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

client.dayOfService = dayOfServiceTextField.text;
client.clientName = clientNameTextField.text;
client.typeOfClient = typeofClientTextField.text;
client.addressLine1 = addressln1TextField.text;
client.addressLine2 = addressln2TextField.text;
client.idCardNumber = idcardNumberTextField.text;


telephoneTextField.text = telephoneNumber;
NSNumberFormatter * f1 = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f1 setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * parsedTelephone = [f1 numberFromString:telephoneNumber];
NSLog(@"%@",parsedTelephone);

[f1 release];

client.telephone = parsedTelephone;
```

Comment: What do you see in the `NSLog` statements? And why are you storing telephone numbers as decimals?

Comment: im supposed to see the parsed number but i dont , How do you suggest to store them in core data ?

Answer (score 4):

`NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` is going to expect a decimal number. If it doesn't find one in the string you pass, it is going to return nothing.

Phone numbers can have any number of spaces, hyphens, plus signs, brackets, hash signs in them. You should store them as `NSString`.

If your other requirement is for a genuine number, I suggest you first attach a number formatter to the text field to validate your input (and have the appropriate keyboard type connected to it), then use the `intValue` method on the text field's text:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[textField.text intValue]];
```

Comment: Thanks ! , i will do that then , however , i have another property that has to be NSNumber , how would you go round it ?